# Can't Create Partitions when installing to MacBook Pro

Tags: system-installation, macbook-pro

When attempting an install on a MacBook Pro from a live usb drive, it fails when creating the partitions. I get:

```
errno=-32
```

It seems to delete any existing partitions just fine, but won't create them. I've installed Ubuntu on this hard disk using another machine, and it worked fine. It's like the MacBook has some kind of lock on writing partitions to the drive. Gparted won't let me manipulate anything either. Any ideas?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; all comments, and the corresponding conversation, have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41915/discussion-on-question-by-crusaderad-cant-create-partitions-when-installing-to).